# Cygwin GDB debugger cannot find debug files

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, gcc, gdb, cygwin

I am using VS Code and I try to debug an executable with cygwin gdb compiled with cygwin gcc.
The problem is that it searches for the files within the build folder:

> C:\XXX\build\gcc\C\XXX\test\source\test_source.cpp

Of course it cannot find it there, because the sources are not in the build folder, but one folder above. Additionally there is a undefined character in the path.

This is the launch.json I use:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\build\\gcc\\XXX\\test\\XXX.exe",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Program Files\\T_cygwin\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This all happens on Windows. I tried out using mingw64 directly where this problem does not occur. So I assume it has to do something with Unix paths. Is there a way to find the right debug files?